# Java restlet nested URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

I used Java Restlet for my server code. My application is simple Blogging site.

It extends `org.restlet.Application` class to define the Router for the application.
I set router for the posts comments as below

```
 router.attach("/posts/{id}/comments", CommentResource.class);
  router.attach("/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}", CommentResource.class);
```

But above router does not work. I always getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Check your request that you are making is not proper at client side.

Comment: Yes, it is going correctly to `http://localhost:8888/posts/22/comments`. Sorry i am getting `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Are you getting any stack traces in the Server JVM logs?

Comment: I am using Google App Engine. In the console, i did not get any errors. Am I doing correct in Restlet Application Router attach?

Comment: add the stacktrace to the question...

Comment: Now it is working. It is a problem in the URL mismatch.